# Python 2.7, Appengine Data Store & Unicode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, utf-8

So I've been reading quite a bit about Unicoding tonight because I was thinking of switching to Jinja2, which requires Unicode to be used everywhere within the app. I think I have a good idea of how to deal with it, but I wanted to hear if this is reasonable before I started to code my app:

> 1. Dealing with External Text-Inputs (via html forms)
>
>    > a) Make sure all html pages are utf-8 encoded.
>    >     b) Once users press submit, make sure the data is converted into Unicode as soon as the python backend receives it...decode(self.request.get('stuff'),utf-8)
>    >     c) Stay in unicode, transfer the outputs to Jinja2 which will always it using the default encoding of utf-8.
> 2. Information from the appengine datastore
>
>    > Because google stores everything as Unicode, all data coming in from the datastore is already unicode and I don't have to worry about anything (yay!)
> 3. Strings within the app
>
>    > Make sure all "" start with a u (i.e. u"hello world"), this will force everything to be in unicode.

Well the above is my strategy to keep everything consistent. Is there anything else I need to account for?

thanks!

Comment: To make sure you get everything in unicode from html pages use html charset utf-8. In each of the the python code make sure you have utf-8 declared on top. If you do that you are fine. If you are using javascript, it also uses unicode so yay!

Comment: you could also use `from __future__ import unicode_strings` so that quoted strings are Unicode without the `u` prefix.

Comment: hey Philipp, i tried unicode_strings..and it gave me an error.  from __future__ import unicode_literals works. Same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to .decode(self.request.get('stuff'),utf-8 if you using webapp or webapp2. The framework respects the input type of the data as specified.

Everything else looks right.

Also I believe that

```
from __future__ import unicode_strings
```

should be

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

and is only available in 2.6 and 2.7 So in App Engine it would only be available if you are using 2.7