# UnicodeDecodeError in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

In my project (using Python, Html & Jinja2) I have a home_page with movie pictures that each picture leads to a specific page with the movie data. When I try to present the page with the movie data I'm getting the following error(I tried to remove each element such as removing moving.summary and the error then flagged on the above paramter):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
        rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
        rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
        return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
        return handler.dispatch()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
        return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\imovie-good\main.py", line 77, in get
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\imovie-good\movie_data.html", line 7, in top-level template code
        <td> Movie Name: {{movie_data.name}}</td>
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my python code:

```
    import webapp2
    import jinja2
    import os
    import datetime
    import time
    import cgi
    from google.appengine.ext import db
    from google.appengine.api import users
    from google.appengine.api import images


    jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    class Movie(db.Model):
        name = db.StringProperty()
        release_date = db.StringProperty()
        duration = db.StringProperty()
        director = db.StringProperty()
        actors = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        summary = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        picture = db.BlobProperty()
        trailer = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    class Movie_Data(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movie_key = self.request.get('movie_key')
            movie_data = Movie.get(movie_key)

    template_values = {'movie_data': movie_data}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('movie_data.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movie = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
            if movie.picture:
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
                self.response.out.write(movie.picture)
            else:
                self.response.out.write("No Image")

    class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movies = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM Movie "
                                "ORDER BY release_date DESC LIMIT 5")
            template_values = { 'movies': movies}                                   
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('home_page.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    class Admin(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            template_values = {}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('admin.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


        def post(self):
            name = self.request.get('name')
            release_date = self.request.get('release_date')
            c = time.strptime(release_date,"%m/%d/%Y")
            release_date = time.strftime("%m%d%Y",c)
            duration = self.request.get('duration')
            director = self.request.get('director')
            actors = self.request.get('actors')
            summary = self.request.get('summary')
            picture = self.request.get('img')
            trailer = self.request.get('trailer')

            movie = Movie(key_name = name)
            movie.release_date = release_date
            movie.duration = duration
            movie.director = director
            movie.actors = actors
            movie.summary = summary
            movie.picture = db.Blob(picture)
            movie.trailer = trailer
            movie.put()
            self.redirect('/')



    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/admin', Admin), ('/', Main), ('/img', Image), ('/movie_data', Movie_Data)], debug=True)
```

This is my html for the home_page:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>Top Movies</th>

            {% for movie in movies %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{movie.key().name() }} &nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href = "/movie_data?movie_key = {{movie.key()}}"> <img src = "/img?img_id={{movie.key()}}"> </td>


            </tr>

            {% endfor %}

            <a href = "/admin">admin</a>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my movie_data html code:

```
  <html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan ="6">{{ movie_data.picture }}</td>
                    <td> Movie Name: {{movie_data.name}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Release Date: {{movie_data.release_date}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Duration (minutes): {{movie_data.duration}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Director: {{movie_data.director}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Actors: {{movie_data.actors}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Summary: {{movie_data.summary}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan ="2"> {{movie_data.trailer}} </td>
                </table>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think depends on the string `movie_data.name`. It's more probable that the entity that creates the error is `movie_data.image`. Review your related code based on [serving blob documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob).

In fact, you need a separate handler for serving images, see the example in [images docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages?hl=en#Serving) or just replace:

```
{{ movie_data.picture }}
```

with

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,{{movie_data.picture.encode("base64")}}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 is unicode-only: [You have to pass unicode objects or bytestrings that only consist of ASCII characters to the render function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#unicode).

So I guess that your `movie.name` is a byte string that contains non-ascii characters.

I suggest you either:

a) Store unicode inside the database, or

b) Convert to unicode inside the template (I'm not sure if this is possible in Jinja2). If it is possible, this syntax is something like:

```
<td> Movie Name: {{unicode(movie_data.name, "utf8")}}</td>
```

I strongly recommend approach a). If using b) (if that syntax is even legal inside jinja templates), you need to know the encoding of the byte string.

A general Python tip is to always use unicode strings. Meaning:

1. Convert external string inputs to unicode as soon as possible (below is an example for HTML form handling). This is known as decoding. `unicode(my_byte_string, encoding)` (or `my_byte_string.decode(encoding)`). `encoding` can be 'ascii', 'utf8' etc.
2. Convert unicode to byte strings as late as possible, if at all. You typically need to convert to byte string if you need to transfer unicode over the network or write a file. This is known as encoding. `my_unicode_string.encode(encoding)`
3. Use unicode literals inside your source code. Use `movie.name = u"Iron Man"` instead of `movie.name = "Iron Man"`

**EDIT**

Looks like you save your movies to the database inside the `Admin.post` method. To store unicode values in the datastore, use code like:

```
name = unicode(self.request.get('name'), "utf8")
# and so on for all the StringProperty values
```

**EDIT 2**

According to [Python 2.7, Appengine Data Store & Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631127/python-2-7-appengine-data-store-unicode) you do not need to decode `self.request.get("...")` when using webapp or webapp2.

I would put a few asserts inside of the `post` method to check if the values you get out of the request are in fact unicode:

```
assert isinstance(self.request.get("name"), unicode)
```

And also check that the object properties that you get out of the data store are unicode (in Main.get):

```
movies = db.GqlQuery("...")
assert all(isinstance(movie.name, unicode) for movie in movies)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you know how to store unicode in the database?

Comment: I believe you simply set the property to unicode when saving the object. ``movie = Movie(); movie.name = u"Iron Man"; movie.put()``.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I tried to add the unicode part to the code but it still doesn't work :\